# Dockerfile: directory ownership issues despite using `COPY --chown=`

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile

I have following simple Dockerfile. Once it is built I face two strange things:

1. at the end the directory `/var/www/html/wp-content` is owned by `root:root` and not by `www-data:www-data` . Why?? I used `COPY --chown=www-data:www-data ...` everywhere...
2. `RUN /bin/chmod 775 /var/www/html/wp-content && /bin/chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/wp-content` doesn't seem to work either... Why?? During the image build I get following line here:

13:49:33 Step 11/11 : RUN /bin/chmod 775 /var/www/html/wp-content && /bin/chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/wp-content
13:49:39  ---> Running in 84cc75b6b392
13:50:01 Removing intermediate container 84cc75b6b392
13:50:01  ---> 0147b7b7049d
13:50:01 Successfully built 0147b7b7049d

Here is the Dockerfile (Docker version 18.03.1-ce)

```
FROM wordpress:latest

# Install requiered packages
RUN apt update && \
    apt install --no-install-recommends -y apt-transport-https procps less nano nmap openssh-client telnet tzdata && \
    apt clean

WORKDIR /var/www/html/
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
USER root
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data htaccess /var/www/html/.htaccess
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data ni/plugins/ /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data ni /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/ni
RUN /bin/chmod 775 /var/www/html/wp-content && /bin/chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/wp-content
```

I tried this:
`RUN /bin/chmod 775 /var/www/html/wp-content && /bin/chown 33:33 -R /var/www/html/wp-content` , where `id www-data` is 33 , but it didn't help...
Interestingly - files inside have proper ownership, only this directory is problematic...

The command to build the image was:

`docker build -t docker.example.com/myapp/myapp_wordpress_development:37 ./DevOps`

Comment: Please include the command and/or yml used to run your container.

Comment: @BMitch - done, thank you!

Comment: How do you _run_ the container?  (Do you use a `docker run -v` option to mount content hiding `/var/www/html` in your image?)

Comment: Along with our request for how you run your container, commands or steps used to check the ownership of the files inside the container would help.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I run the container using Ansible docker_container module... but without mounting volumes. What I indeed do after I run the container - I run another one which uses  --volumes-from first_wordpress_container. To check the directory ownership - I do `docker exec -it first_wordpress_container bash` and then run `ls -lah`.

Comment: @BMitch, @DavidMaze - if you build the container the same way with the same file - do you also get the directory `/var/www/html/wp-content` owned by `root:root`?